# Error when creating Kubeflow cluster: ContainerCluster in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a ContainerCluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I am going through the procedure of https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/kubeflow-gke-docs/docs/deploy/deploy-cli/. And I received the following error after `make apply`:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "build/container.cnrm.cloud.google.com_v1beta1_containercluster_kubeflow-test2.yaml": ContainerCluster in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a ContainerCluster: strict decoding error: unknown field "metadata.clusterName"
make[2]: *** [Makefile:44: apply-cnrm] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/projects/glassdome/kubeflow-distribution/kubeflow/common/cnrm'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:49: apply] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/projects/glassdome/kubeflow-distribution/kubeflow/common/cnrm'
make: *** [Makefile:83: apply] Error 1
```

What can be the reason behind the error? How can I solve it? Thank you!

I tried to remove `metadata.clusterName` but it returned automatically after `make apply`.

**UPDATE:**

You can do the following to resolve the issue:

1. run `make apply` first time and recieve the error
2. remove `metadata.clusterName` from `common/cnrm/build/container.cnrm.cloud.google.com_v1beta1_containercluster_$YOUR_NAME$.yaml`
3. Copy `common/cnrm/Makefile` to `common/cnrm/Makefile_copy` (just to restore it if something wrong happens)
4. Remove `$(MAKE) apply-cnrm build_dir=$(build_dir)` from `common/cnrm/Makefile`
5. Rerun `make apply`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `metadata.clusterName` is a good option to start with but the problems you see where it comes up on its own may be caused by some scripts or Makefiles that repeat a YAML file on every run.

Here are a few options to check.

1. Test your scripts/Makefiles:

   Check if your Kubernetes regenerates a YAML file. If this happens, you will need to make sure to remove metadata.clusterName and fix the problem in these scripts or makefiles to prevent it from being included.
2. Verify Kubernetes Operator:

   Make sure that the Kubernetes Operator or CRD (Custom Resource Definition) version matches your Kubernetes cluster version. If your Operator version is too new to your Kubernetes cluster version, you may encounter issues like this since it will not recognize it. In addition, make sure that the Kubeflow Operator adn the kubernetes cluster version matches to avoid errors.
3. Updating your Kubernetes API version:

   If you are using an older version of the Kubernetes API, you may want to consider upgrading to a newer version that supports the metadata.clusterName field. This could be updating your Kubernetes client (`kubectl`) or even the Kubernetes clusters themselves. However, it is important to note that updating your version of Kubernetes may have additional effects and should be tested carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Could you tell me how can I update Kubernetes API version to v2beta1? 

The following codes:
`export PIPELINE_VERSION="2.0.0-alpha.4"

kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
kubectl wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/applications.app.k8s.io
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/env/dev?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"`

gives an error: Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:

And finally, does not update anything

Comment: Here are some common steps you can take to update the API version of your Kubernetes objects:

Check the version of the resource API supported by your Kubernetes cluster. You can do this with the kubectl api-versions command.

In the Kubernetes YAML file of the resource, change the apiVersion field to the version you want to use (in your case, v2beta1). Make sure all other fields in the YAML file match the new API version.

Apply the updated YAML file using the command kubectl apply -f <filename>.

Comment: Here are some helpful links for your use case:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/
https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/